# Sharing form logic between Django Rest Framework and UI

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

My django app has an entity `Campaign`. For my UI, I've implemented `CampaignForm` which has logic that is not trivial.

I have also integrated Django Rest Framework to allow CRUD functionalities of the `Campaign` class via an API.

After searching on Google and DRF's docs, I found out that *there is no official way to integrate Django Forms into DRF*.

**I must be mistaken right?**

The only thing I see is that DRF has custom validators but I don't think it can port all the logic of my form to DRF's validators.

How can I include the logic of my CampaignForm into my API?

Reference:

```
class CampaignForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = '__all__'
        help_texts = {
            'dayparting_schedule': schedule_help_text
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        - All Active MUST have dayparting schedule defined
        - If schedule is set then timezone must also be set
        """
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        status = cleaned_data.get('status')
        dayparting_schedule = cleaned_data.get('dayparting_schedule')

        if status == Campaign.ACTIVE:
            # if there is no existing dayparting_schedule OR
            # if this form does not have dayparting_schedule
            if dayparting_schedule is None \
                    and self.instance.dayparting_schedule is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('dayparting_schedule cannot be empty for Active'))

        schedule_present = bool(dayparting_schedule)
        timezone_present = bool(cleaned_data.get('dayparting_timezone'))

        # XOR: 0^0, 1^1 => 0, otherwise 1
        if schedule_present ^ timezone_present:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _('dayparting_schedule and dayparting_timezone must be set together.'))

        return cleaned_data

    def clean_dayparting_schedule(self, *args, **kwargs):
        schedule = self.cleaned_data.get('dayparting_schedule')
        if not schedule:
            return
        self.validate_schedule(schedule)
        return schedule

    def validate_schedule(self, yaml_s):
        dic = yaml.load(yaml_s)
        if not isinstance(dic, dict):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Invalid Format: Please follow the format above'))
        if set(dic.keys()) != set(['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('Invalid Format: Missing mon/tue/wed/thu/fri/sun'))
        for v in dic.values():
            if not re.match('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$', v):
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('Invalid Format: value must be 1200-1500'))
```

Answer (score 0):

*In short:* Django rest framwork has `serializers` modul which is rest equivalent to the Django's `forms`.

You should create `Serializer` (or `ModelSerializer`) which will handle the logic same way it does in your `CampaignForm`.

Have look at [Serializers | Django Rest Framework Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).

Comment: Is there a way to combine of them together so i can test the logic in one place? (As you can see, my form's logic is not trivial and heavily tested)

Comment: You can put your logic on the model level and call these methods both from form and serializer.

Comment: Also do not recommend using `__all__` in the Meta fields attribute, it's not safe.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I am missing something? Why is this functionality not native?

Comment: Which functionality do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your hands dirty:

```
class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ... 

    def validate(self, data):
        """
        During updating, self.instance will be available.
        """
        form = CampaignForm(data, instance=self.instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            return data
        raise serializers.ValidationError(str(form.errors))
```